# Cypress docker container unable to connect to my Angular localhost using dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cypress

So I am currently using MEAN Stack (But MySQL Instead of MongoDB).
And I am using Cypress for e2e testing. I am currently dockerizing my application and am facing the following issue.

I first deploy the angular and node container.
Then after the angular web application is built, I launch the cypress container.
The issue with that is my cypress container's localhost is unable to connect to angular's localhost.
Which is not the issue with Node and Angular connection.

so I am facing the following error

```
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:

  > http://localhost:4200

We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your `baseUrl`.

Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.

We will try connecting to it 3 more times...
We will try connecting to it 2 more times...
We will try connecting to it 1 more time...

Cypress failed to verify that your server is running.
```

I am using individual dockerfiles rather than Docker-compose as the building time of the angular file is rather long and so I am unable to use alias functionality of docker-compose(As the angular docker is still building when the cypress runs the command)

Is there a way to solve this issue?

For more information my Dockerfiles are below:
Dockerfile-Angular

```
FROM node:10.16.3

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install \
    && npm install -g @angular/cli@6.2.9

# add app
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 4200
# start app
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Node API Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.16.3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/API

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/API/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/API/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app/API

EXPOSE 4711
CMD ["node","server"]
```

Cypress DockerFile

```
FROM cypress/base:10.11.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install dependencies
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install --save-dev cypress
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify
RUN  npm run cypress:run
```

Also, this setup is for development purpose not production.

---

Update
I am not using the compose file. I am starting the docker container individually.

Angular 
`docker run -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app -p 4200:4200 --name angular -it angular`

Node 
`docker run -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app/API -p 4711:4711 --name api -it api`

Cypress 
`docker run -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app --name cypress -it cypress`

Comment: share your docker compose file/docker run command as well.

Comment: I am not using the compose file. I am starting the docker container individually.
Angular
 ```docker run -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app -p 4200:4200 --name angular -it angular```
Node
```docker run -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app/API -p 4711:4711 --name api -it api```
Cypress
```docker run -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app --name cypress -it cypress```

Comment: you have to change the base url of  cypress.  change it to http://<docker-host-ip>:4200